# Day trips from cities as part of a Turkey vacation

Tags: air-travel, turkey, tourist-visas

I am new to this forum, so pardon me if you find this question stupid or not suitable for this forum.

One of my friends wants to go to Turkey from Pakistan on 15 days visit, it will be purely for the sake of tourism.

Is it possible to visit multiple cities within 15 days? Can she go back and forth to different cities, like if my friend makes a city (lets say Istanbul) her destination, can she go and visit any city and come back to Istanbul in a day?

As an example, during my visit to UAE, I stayed in Dubai but went to visit Abu Dhabi and came back to Dubai same day then went to Sharjah next day and came back to Dubai same day because these states are very near to Dubai. Can this be done in Turkey as well? If yes then which cities are recommended to visit?

**Question edited according to the suggestions of members**

Comment: The question is not stupid at all but it is indeed not really suitable for this forum. We don't want subjective or open-ended questions asking for recommendations or an itinerary. But you can ask several focused question if you want (examples would be: How is the road network in Turkey? How do busses and trains compare for intercity travel? etc.)

Comment: The answer to question 3 is: Istanbul (although I personally know people who went directly to Antalya or Bodrum for beach holidays without ever visiting it).

Comment: @Relaxed So, I think I _shouldn't_ try to answer since this kind of questions are not welcome in here, right?

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, I think that's best. In practice, the question will almost certainly be closed in a couple of hours, once enough people have voted. At the same time, if you do answer anyway and get at least one vote, it will remain archived like [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/best-way-to-travel-from-france-to-switzerland-austria-and-germany) for example. It's not recommended but there is nothing to stop you from doing it, if you will.

Comment: First, welcome to the site. Like Relaxed says, this question isn't stupid, but not really something we can answer here. I'd recommend looking at some guidebooks for Turkey to get an idea of where people typically go and what there is to see. That said, I'd be looking at Istanbul for several days at least, Cappadocia (perhaps with a balloon trip), and Ephesus (probably staying in Izmir). Depending on your interest and time, you could add a beach resort as well.

Comment: Turkey is a big country and it's going to be necessary to do more than day trips to see a lot. That said, a search for [Istanbul day trips](https://www.google.com/search?q=istanbul+day+trips&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) will have some promising options. But don't forget to explore Istanbul too; there's a lot to see there.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for the response but don't you think question 2 is more focused and is eligible for an answer that if there are cities having 1-2 hrs of travel time among them? :) Pardon for the rest.

Comment: @ZachLipton Thanks for giving the hints, appreciate it, From the search it seems that Cappadocia can be visited in a day.

Comment: @HappyDev Yes, you could edit your question to focus on this point.

Comment: @SonerGönül seems you are from Turkey and you could help me in designing the trip. I'd really be grateful for all the assistance.

Comment: @HappyDev Sure, I will gladly help but you need to be _more_ specific when you asking a question. For example, what kind of activities, places like to see? What do you expect to see on you trip? Do you have enough money to afford a few cities for flight tickets which is the fastest way you can travel? If you wanna see great natural view, go "Karadeniz" (specially "Sumela Monastery"), if you wanna go swim and sunbathe, go "Akdeniz", if you wanna taste great food and historical places, go "Gaziantep" and "Şanlıurfa", if you wanna see bosphorus, go "İstanbul".

Comment: @HappyDev And I have to say, "15 days" is _long_ time period in my opinion. If you have enough money to flight, you can visit _all_ of those cities in that period and I can guaranteed that you will had a great time. Check http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/ for more information as well.

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks for the response, actually my friend is going to visit Turkey first time and she wants to explore the country as much as she can, though budget is limited but for the sake of tourism a little expensive is also Okay :) but she is more interested in Road travel than air-travel.That is why she needs to know if it is okay to stay in Istanbul? and then visit a few cities(or any city) near to Istanbul by road , per day each (if it is possible)?I mean we don't know if their are cities near enough to Istanbul to travel to and come back to Istanbul in a day.

Comment: @SonerGönül One more thing, do you think Istanbul is a good choice to be stayed in during the visit?

Comment: @HappyDev Sure. You can see a lot of places _even_ if you wanna spend your all 15 days in İstanbul.